# How do I properly truncate a 64 bit float to a 32 bit truncated float and back (dropping precision) with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, floating-point, binary, precision

So obviously there's no 32 bit float, but if we're trying to store big data efficiently and many of our values are floats no greater than 100,000 with exactly 2 decimal places, it makes sense to store the 64 bit value in 32 bits by dropping the bits representing the precision that we don't need.

I tried doing this by simply writing to a 64 bit BE float buffer like so and slicing the first 4 bytes:

```
// float32 = Number between 0.00 and 100000.00
const setFloat32 = (float32) => {
    b64.writeDoubleBE(float32, 0) // b64 = 64 bit buffer
    b32 = b64.slice(0, 4)
    return b32;
}
```

And reading it by adding on 4 empty bytes:

```
// b32 = the 32 bit buffer from the previous func
const readFloat32 = (b32) => {
    // b32Empty = empty 32 bit buffer
    return Buffer.concat([b32, b32Empty]).readDoubleBE(0);
}
```

But this modified flat decimals like:

```
1.85 => 1.8499994277954102
2.05 => 2.049999237060547
```

How can I fix my approach to do this correctly, and do so in the most efficient manner for read speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to keep two decimals of precision, you can convert your value to a shifted integer and store that:

```
function shiftToInteger(val, places) {
    // multiply by a constant to shift the decimals you want to keep into
    // integer positions, then use Math.round() or Math.floor()
    // to truncate the rest of the decimals - depending upon which behavior you want
    // then return the shifted integer that will fit into a U32 for storage
    return Math.round(val * (10 ** places));   
}
```

This creates a shifted integer that can then be stored in a 32 bit value (with the value limits you described), such as a `Uint32Array` or `Int32Array`.  To use it when you retrieve it from storage, you would then divide it by 100 to convert it back to a standard Javascript float for usage.

The key is to convert whatever decimal precision you want to keep to an integer so you can store that in a non-float type of value that is just large enough for your max anticipated value.  You can storage efficiency because you're using all the storage bits for the desired precision rather than wasting a lot of unnecessary storage bits on the decimal precision that you don't need to keep.

Here's an example:

```js
function shiftToInteger(val, places) {
    return Math.round(val * (10 ** places));   
}

function shiftToFloat(integer, places) {
    return integer / (10 ** places);
}


let x = new Uint32Array(10);
x[0] = shiftToInteger(1.85, 2);
console.log(x[0]);                   // output shifted integer value
console.log(shiftToFloat(x[0], 2));  // convert back to decimal value
```